# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle

I got an email from a user when he sees the following error output when he's using our web site.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "WEB_OWNER.SSFP_GET_WE_OBJ", line 300
ORA-06512: at line 1

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:137)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:281)
```

This is error from oracle webconnect, Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0).

Any idea?

Comment: Not without seeing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the error and is common in all programming languages.
Your variable is too small for the value you are putting in it. This is a common pl/sql exception. The easy way to keep this from happening is to anchor your pl/sql variables to columns. Do NOT do this

variableName variableType(Variable length)

If you change a column, to make it longer you need to change code to make the variable wider. Do this:

variableName column.table%TYPE

So if you want to base a variable off of the employees table and the customer name field do this

vCustomerName employees.customerName%type;

This has been available in pl/sql for 15-20 years.

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small